# check/uncheck box is not working with prop fucntion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i used `.prop`, `.attr`, `.removeAttr`, nothing seems to work.

```
$.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"{{base_url()}}admin/configurations/GetFormData/"+FormID,
                    dataType:"json",
                    success:function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        if(!($.isEmptyObject(response))){
                            $.each(response,function(key,value){
                                $("#formName").val(value.FormName);
                                $("#formPath").val(value.FormPath);
                                $("#formCIPath").val(value.FormCIPath);
                                if(value.IsMenuLink !=='0'){
                                    $("#isMenuLink").prop( "checked", true );
                                }
                                else{
                                    $("#isMenuLink").prop( "checked", false);
                                }
                                console.log(value.IsMenuLink);
                                //alert(value.ExtimatedIncome);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }); //---  End of $.ajax  ---//
```

Json returns IsMenuLink to `"1"` or `"0"`.

so when its `"1"` i want it to be checked and on `"0"` it should be unchecked.

but problem is no matter what i use prop or attr it don't affect the checkbox.

BTW i am using switch checkbox..

Here is the HTML

```
<input class="make-switch" id="isMenuLink" type="checkbox" data-on-color="success" data-on-text="Yes" data-off-text="NO" data-off-color="danger">
```

Comment: What this `(!($.isEmptyObject(response)))` return? I mean did you check if enters in each function?

Comment: Check the javascript console, maybe theres an ajax error. What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Have you confirmed you are hitting the right branch of your `if`/`else` statement?

Comment: @Alek
it checks if the json return is not empty then it assigns the values to the textboxes.
All text boxes are Populating Fine.

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez
Cant find any jQuery errors in console for this call.
i am using 1.10.2

Comment: @Quentin
Sorry sir, i don't get what branch?

Comment: Try using this: `if(value.IsMenuLink !='0'){` .. maybe the value is a number and not a string

Comment: Or just show us the response

Comment: You sure it's "0" and "1" and not 0 and 1 since you are doing typesafe comparison? try console logging (value !== "0") :)

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez
i dont think its an if else issue cuz i commented out the if else portion just now and put the `$("#isMenuLink").prop("checked", true);` directly in script. but still no progress.

Comment: @SizzlingCode well then use javascript breakpoints and check everything there.. you are missing something in the response

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez
yes i just figured out the problem. but now gonna have to try to solve it..
it is bootstrap checkbox which is styled in switch. so it dosent work with prop but i guess i have to change the attribute in the parent div from `bootstrap-switch-on` to `bootstrap-switch-off` or something like that..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i finally Figured out the solution, i dont know if its the best one or not for me. but atleast it works. if anyone have better jquery prposition please answer it to make the jquery more short.

anyhow the problem was not with if/else statement neither the .prop.

but i was using the bootstrap switch checkboxes which when page is loaded add classes and do stuff...

however it turns out i had to change the class from off to on to change the checkbox value.

```
                        if(value.IsMenuLink !=='0'){
                            $("#isMenuLink").parent().parent().removeClass('bootstrap-switch-off');
                            $("#isMenuLink").parent().parent().addClass('bootstrap-switch-on');
                        }
                        else{
                            $("#isMenuLink").parent().parent().removeClass('bootstrap-switch-on');
                            $("#isMenuLink").parent().parent().addClass('bootstrap-switch-off');
                        }
```

if anyone can suggest better jquery which is shorter then this to swap classes please tell.